# Create a new field inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm using the combo Express (Node.js) and Mongoose to make a REST API. I'm trying to make the login using a JWT token but I've got a problem. When I execute the following code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

// other code

_api.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    const data = req.body;
    // some data control

    User.findOne({ username: data.username}, function(err, doc) {
        if (hash(password) == doc.password) { // password check
            myToken = generateToken(); // generating the token
            doc.jwtToken = myToken; // including the generated token to the response

            res.status(200).json(doc); // return the final JSON to client
        }
    }
}
```

the final JSON returned by the API doesn't have the field "jwtToken":"mygeneratedtoken" and this is strange. I included other times new fields inside a JSON with the same syntax and it worked. I tried to use a tmp variable to which I assigned the doc content (that is a javascript object) and then I added the jwtToken filed and return the tmp variable. But nothing.

Can someone explain me if there is something wrong with my code or if there is something that I need to know?

Comment: Please verify `generateToken` is not returning undefined.

Comment: no, the generateToken is returning a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents returned by mongoose are immutable, and thus assignment to `doc.jwtToken` does not modify the object. You can either use the `lean` method to modify the query, or `toObject` to convert the document to a regular javascript object. Try:

```
var docObject = doc.toObject();
docObject.jwtToken = myToken;
res.status(200).json(docObject);
```